# Translate site: missing required parameter for route

Tags: php, laravel

I have a select menu for the user to select 1 of 3 languages (english, spanish and german). The goal is that if the user select english, all content of the site changes to english, and the same for the other languages.

I have the code below for this but its not working. It appears `missing required parameter for route site.translate`.

The LanguageController:

```
class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function changeLanguage($language)
    {
        if(Session::has(locale)){
            session()->set('locale', $language);}
        else{
            session()->set('locale', 'en');
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pt-4 pb-4">
  <div class="footer-list">
    <h3>Language</h3>
    <form method="get" action="{{route('site.translate')}}">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <select name="language" class="form-control font-weight-normal text-gray" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option selected class="selected" value="de">German</option>
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="de">German</option>
        <option value="es">Spanish</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

LocaleMiddleware:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;

    class LocaleMiddleware
    {

        protected $languages = ['en','fr','es', 'de'];


        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            if(!session()->has('locale'))
            {
                session()->put('locale', $request->getPreferredLanguage($this->languages));
            }

            app()->setLocale(session('locale'));

            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('lang/{language}', [
    'uses' => 'LanguageController@changeLanguage',
    'as'   =>'site.translate'
]);
```

Comment: It looks like your route is missing a parameter. It needs to look something like this `route('post.show', ['post' => 1]);` Can you show us your web route for trainslate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your route is requiring a parameter. `lang/{language}`
You do not need to require a parameter when doing a form post. Also, you need to have your form to be `POST` not `GET`

So do something like this instead.

Route:

```
Route::post('/lang', [
    'uses' => 'LanguageController@changeLanguage',
    'as'   =>'site.translate'
]);
```

View:

```
<div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pt-4 pb-4">
  <div class="footer-list">
    <h3>Language</h3>
    <form method="post" action="{{route('site.translate')}}">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <select name="language" class="form-control font-weight-normal text-gray" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option selected class="selected" value="de">German</option>
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="de">German</option>
        <option value="es">Spanish</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function changeLanguage(Request $request)
    {
        if(Session::has(locale)){
            session()->set('locale', $request->language);}
        else{
            session()->set('locale', 'en');
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know why appears "Use of undefined constant locale - assumed 'locale'"?

Comment: @Carrick start by debugging the controller. Add a normal submit button in the form, not jQuery. Do `dd($request->language);` in the controller to see if the value is bing passed in from the form. Then see if the conditional logic is the issue if it is being passed correctly.

Comment: @Carrick create a new question and I'll answer it for you.

Comment: $request->language shows the correct result "de", "es,", etc, depending on the select option selected.